# Can I upload files from a custom website form to Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I have clients uploading files directly to my Dropbox folder. I was curious if I can build a website form that uploads the file to my Dropbox folder and also saves the forms data to my server with a reference to the file that was uploaded to Dropbox? They are legal documents and I don't want to worry about security if Dropbox handles that.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204467893-Managing-sensitive-files-with-a-server- ]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it should definitely be possible.
You would have to use the dropbox api:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js

There are some javascript examples that would likely be what you would need to go directly to dropbox without going to your server first.

Comment: I know it's possible but there is little or no information when I first started looking into the problem. For example, here is page on the [Javascript API you linked to](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/javascript#documentation)

Comment: As noted in the other forum, each user would need their own individual account for the upload.  you could not securely connect to a single dropbox account using javascript.  You could run some server side code on your end to know when they attempt to upload to their account and likely get the files so that you have access from that point without the files going through your webserver.